# laravel5.2で検索結果の詳細表示

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

お世話になります。
http://qiita.com/zaburo/items/9fefa3f6834b2e79b734
こちらを参考にし、laravelで検索を実装することができました。

しかしながら検索の詳細表示ができず困っています。
routes.php

```
Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'SearchController@detail');
```

SearchController.php

```
        public function detail($id) {

            $query = DB::table('item_master')->where('id',$id);

            return view('layouts.detail.index')->with('query',$query);
    }
```

layouts.detail.index.blade.php

```
<div>{{$query->id}}</div>
<div>{{$query->item_name}}</div>
```

こちらで取得することができません。
おそらく$queryでvar_dumpすると意図しないものがでてくる(無限ループ？)のでおそらくそこなのですが
何が間違っているのかわかりません。
ちなみにitem_masterテーブルには一意のidとitem_nameが入っています。

大変低レベルな質問で申し訳ないのですが
ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[その記事の詳細表示の節](http://qiita.com/zaburo/items/9fefa3f6834b2e79b734#5%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA)を見ると、次のようなコードが書かれていますね。

```
public function show($id)
{
    //レコードを検索
    $user = User::find($id);
    //検索結果をビューに渡す
    return view('users.show')->with('user',$user);
}
```

この `User::find()` を `DB::table(..)->where(..)` に書き換えたようですが、**これらは使い方が異なるため、単純に置き換えることはできません**。

`User` はLaravelのEloquentという機能を使った、usersテーブルへのアクセスを担うクラスで、`find()` は指定したIDのレコードを単一のオブジェクトで返します。

一方あなたが使っているのはQuery Builderという機能です。これは`DB::table(..)` に対して順番に `select()` `join()` `where()` などのメソッドを呼び出すことでクエリを組み立て、`get()` `first()` などのメソッドで結果を取得する、という流れになります。ですから、

```
$query = DB::table('item_master')->where('id',$id);
```

これではクエリを組み立てただけで、結果を取得していません。

例えばEloquentの `find()` のように一件だけ取得したいのであれば、出来上がったクラスに対して `first()` を呼び出します。この結果にはEloquentと同様にしてアクセスができます。

```
$item = DB::table('item_master')->where('id', $id)->first();
// この$itemに対して、例えば$item->item_nameとしてアクセスできる
```

参考 [データベース：クエリービルダー 5.1 Laravel](http://readouble.com/laravel/5/1/ja/queries.html)

・・・と、Query Builderの話をしてきましたが、Qiita記事のようにEloquentを使うことも可能です。それぞれ自由度や書き方が異なりますから、お好きな方を選んで構いません。

- [初めてのLaravel 5.1 : (9) モデルの作成 – ララ帳](https://laravel10.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/%E5%88%9D%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AElaravel-5-9-%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90/)
- [Eloquent：利用の開始 5.1 Laravel](http://readouble.com/laravel/5/1/ja/eloquent.html)